# Is there any way to animate a conic-gradient in CSS?

Tags: css, css-transitions, conic-gradients

I have a circular graph that I want to use to track progress. I use this SASS definition:

```
@for $i from 0 through 100
    .circle-chart-#{$i}
        background: conic-gradient($cyan $i * 1%, $graphBackground $i * 1%)
```

Is there any way to animate (or fake animation) the change of the conic-gradient in CSS?

Answer (score 2):

As for pure CSS implementation, you can try:

```css
@property --percent {
  syntax: '<percentage>';
  inherits: false;
  initial-value: 0%;
}
```

then you can use `transition: --percent curve time;` for manipulating `conic-gradient` percentages.

```css
.circle-chart {
    background: conic-gradient(cyan var(--percent), white var(--percent));
}
```

Reference: https://dev.to/afif/we-can-finally-animate-css-gradient-kdk