CSS circle progress bar is not animating
I am unable to get the circle bar to animate. I attempted adding transition: all 600ms ease; but that didn't work. I am not sure if CSS animation supports conic-gradient.


jQuery(function ($) {
  $('.bar').addClass('animate');
});
.icon {
  width: 146px;
  height: 146px;
  padding: 36px;
  position: relative;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.icon .bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}
.icon .bar::before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  inset: 0;
  background: conic-gradient(#00a451 0%, #e1e1e1 0%);
  z-index: 1;
  transition: all 600ms ease;
}
.icon .bar::after {
  content: "";
  background-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 110px;
  height: 110px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 2;
}
.icon .bar.animate::before {
  background: conic-gradient(#00a451 var(--stat-bar), #e1e1e1 0%);
}
<div class="icon">
  <div class="bar" style="--stat-bar:75%"></div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




Please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

@C3roe i was already editing my question while you was posting your comment.

You can't just transition CSS variables like that, you need to create a custom @property first - https://stackoverflow.com/a/74079080/1427878

@C3roe I updated my script to what you advised but it broke my css. I am no longer able to see the green fill. I have updated the code snippet.

Fix: I have used the following https://codepen.io/t_afif/pen/XWaPXZO as an inspiration and updated my script accordingly and now it works as intended.


jQuery(function ($) {
  $('.module').addClass('animate');
});
@property --stat-bar{
  syntax: '<number>';
  inherits: true;
  initial-value: 0;
}

.icon{
  width: 146px;
  height: 146px;
  padding: 36px;
  position: relative;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

.icon .bar {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.icon .bar:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  inset: 0;
  background:
    radial-gradient(farthest-side, #00a451 98%, #0000) top/22px 22px no-repeat,
    conic-gradient(#00a451 calc(var(--stat-bar) * 1%), #0000 0);
  -webkit-mask: radial-gradient(farthest-side, #0000 calc(99% - 22px), #000 calc(100% - 22px));
  mask: radial-gradient(farthest-side, #0000 calc(99% - 22px), #000 calc(100% - 22px));
  background-size:
    0 0,
    auto;
}

.animate .icon .bar{
  animation:progress-bar 1s .5s both;
}
@keyframes progress-bar {
  from{--stat-bar:0}
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<section class="module">
  <div class="icon">
      <div class="bar" style="--stat-bar:80;"></div>
  </div>
</section>




Is this an answer to your question? If so, please add an explanation. If not, delete it and edit your question

@j08691 i added a comment to the answer and to my question


Here I used your initial CSS and HTML as a starting point, trimmed CSS and HTML to the minimal necessary. All you need to add then is a CSS @property of <percentage> (or <number>) with an initial value of 0% that animates to any end-value stored inside an element's style="--data-bar:N%;" attribute.
PS: you don't need an entire jQuery library in order to assign classes to elements, and also you don't need the wrapping .icon element parent



document.querySelectorAll(".bar").forEach(el => el.classList.add("animate"));
@property --stat-bar {
  syntax: '<percentage>';
  inherits: true;
  initial-value: 0%;
}

.bar {
  display: inline-flex;
  position: relative;
  height: 150px;
  aspect-ratio: 1;
  inset: 0;
  mask: radial-gradient(#0000 32%, #000 calc(32% + 1px)); /* Hole */ 
  border-radius: 50%;

  &::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    inset: 0;
    background: conic-gradient(#00a451 var(--stat-bar), #e1e1e1 0%);
  }
  
  &.animate::before {
    animation: statBar 1s forwards;
  }
}

@keyframes statBar {
  from {
    --stat-bar: 0%;
  }
}
<div class="bar" style="--stat-bar:75%;"></div>
<div class="bar" style="--stat-bar:25%;"></div>




With css animation not possible in this case, please see here for a reference.
I have implemented some extra code with the JS. Please review the attributes added animate-end="75" animate-speed="10".


$(function () {
  $(".bar").addClass("animate");
  var animationEnd = parseInt($(".bar").attr("animate-end"), 10);
  var speed = parseInt($(".bar").attr("animate-speed"), 10);
  var initial = 0;

  if (!isNaN(animationEnd) && animationEnd >= initial) {
    var intervalId = setInterval(() => {
      $(".bar").attr("style", `--stat-bar: ${initial}%`);
      initial++;

      if (initial > animationEnd) {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
      }
    }, speed);
  }
});
.icon {
    width: 146px;
    height: 146px;
    padding: 36px;
    position: relative;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}

.icon .bar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}

.icon .bar::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-radius: 50%;
    inset: 0;
    background: conic-gradient(#00a451 0%, #e1e1e1 0%);
    z-index: 1;
    transition: none;
}

.icon .bar::after {
    content: "";
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 110px;
    height: 110px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    z-index: 2;
}

.icon .bar.animate::before {
    background: conic-gradient(#00a451 var(--stat-bar), #e1e1e1 0%);
}
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon">
    <div class="bar" animate-end="75" animate-speed="10"></div>
</div>




@DarkBee that's why mentioned in this case. Please let me know as well how we can sort this.

@MaheshThorat your solution seems to ignore the animation needing to be triggered when .animate class is added. You are forcing the animation with javascript. I am pretty sure this can be done via css like in this codepen https://codepen.io/t_afif/pen/XWaPXZO but I wasn't able to repurpose it to solve my problem.

@DarkBee I don't think there is a solution with dynamic width without using javascript. Your SO example says so. Temami solution is not dynamic. This is his fiddle on the same https://jsfiddle.net/a91ebko8/1/. Even the blog post ends with, "You can use it as is, or you can extend it to suit your needs, sprinkling in a little bit of JavaScript if you need to"
Do you have a css only solution?

@codeandcloud Unsure what you mean with dynamic width here? See the comment made by OP above as well - Mahesh just states it's not possible without giving an explanation why it wouldn't be possible.

@DarkBee I said only about this case. There are many more alternative you can try and implement. And why not working. Please see this url once

You should add these details inside your answer for future readers
